# Inview multiple divs with the same class calling the function for all divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I call the function separately for each div with the same name class?

```
$( window ).on( 'load', function() {
    $('.section').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
        if (isInView) {
          // element is now visible in the viewport
          slideBlocks();
        } else {
          // element has gone out of viewport
        }
      });

});
```

The function slideBlocks() is called for all divs with the class name 'section' when the first div with the class name section enters in view port.

I am using https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview

Answer (score 1):

Make `sideBlocks()` work on some other class like: `.sideblocks`

```
$( window ).on( 'load', function() {
    $('.section').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
        if (isInView) {
          $(this).addClass('.sideblocks'); //or $(this).addClass('.section.sideblocks');
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass('.sideblocks'); //or $(this).removeClass('.section.sideblocks');
        }
        slideBlocks();
      });
});
```